# Dynamically Create String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops

There is a hash `{'results' => [], 'snow' => [], 'ham' => [], 'plow' => [] }`

and I want to build a string dynamically (the keys may change), which has all the keys, excluding "results", which looks like this `"snow + ham + plow"`

How do i do this?

Comment: yeah you're right, i was using python syntax, i'll edit the post and fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Hash#keys` to get the keys, `Array#reject` to reject the "results" one, and `Array#join` to join them into a String:

```
hash.keys.reject { |k| k == "results" }.join(" + ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Two other ways (#1 being my preference):

```
h = {'results' => [], 'snow' => [], 'ham' => [], 'plow' => [] }
```

**#1**

```
(h.keys - ['results']).join(' + ') #=> "snow + ham + plow"
```

**#2**

```
a = h.keys
a.delete('results')
a.join(' + ') #=> "snow + ham + plow"
```

Comment: Well, without explicit enumeration. `Array#delete` and `Array.join` both have to iterate behind the scenes.

Comment: Good point, @Chuck.  No denying that.  (Applies to `keys` as well.) Edited.  Readers: formerly I said "Without iterating:".